# How to save Wordpress Options as an array?

Tags: options, array

How do I save options as an array using forms? I don't want to use Settings API.

Here's working form that saves 3 options separately:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="options.php">
   <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>

   <input type="text" name="option1" value="<?php echo get_option('option1');  ?>" />
   <input type="text" name="option2" value="<?php echo get_option('option2'); ?>" />
   <input type="text" name="option3" value="<?php echo get_option('option3'); ?>" />

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
<input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="option1,option2,option3" />
<p class="submit"><input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" /></p>
</form>
```

And here's how it should look for an array, but this method doesn't work (I guess the problem lies in input called page_options:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="options.php">
   <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>
   <?php $options = get_option('my_options'); ?>

   <input type="text" name="option1" value="<?php echo $options['option1']; ?>" />
   <input type="text" name="option2" value="<?php echo $options['option2']; ?>" />
   <input type="text" name="option3" value="<?php echo $options['option3']; ?>" />

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
<input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="my_options" />
<p class="submit"><input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" /></p>
</form>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried...

```
 <input type="text" name="my_options[option1]" value="<?php echo $options['option1']; ?>" />
 <input type="text" name="my_options[option2]" value="<?php echo $options['option2']; ?>" />
 <input type="text" name="my_options[option3]" value="<?php echo $options['option3']; ?>" />?
```

I should say though (and maybe you have), that you should register your settings and perform necessary validation checks on the input - or if you really don't want to use the Settings API, disregard it completely and 'manually' collect the form data, check the data, check nonces etc and add to the database.

Comment: isn't it a dictionary rather than an array?

Comment: In PHP an array is used as a dictionary: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: thanks. I use a different language. I solved my problem like my_options[0], my_options[1] ... instead of using String keys because I needed index numbers